# Jquery: How to deselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a selector with two options.
Depending on the option will appear a set of checkboxes.

Here you can see it:  http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/24/edit

The problem is that if i select some checkboxes and then choose another option in the selector, that previous checkboxes remain selected and this create problems.

So what i have to do is: when one option of the selector is selected, as the very first thing, i UNCHECKED all the checkboxes.

Do you know how can i do it?

Thank you very much.
I hope to have been clear about the question.
If you don't understand something ask away!

Comment: Use radio buttons, that's what they are there for.

Comment: Is not possible to deselect chekcboxes with JQuery?

Comment: Of course it is, but radio buttons has this functionality as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automaticly uncheck all of the checkboxs on select change, so add this in the select on change at the top

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    this.checked = false;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i needed! In seven minutes i will be able to check it as the correct one.

Comment: Yes of course. I have already modify my project and is working smoothly now!

Answer (score 0):

To deselect checkbox try `$('#id').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a group of options, but only one should be checked at a time, you should use radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="groupName">
```

The `name` attribute defines the group of radio buttons that will relate to each other. This means of all the inputs of `type="radio"` with `name="groupName"`, only 1 will be checked at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this :

```
$("fieldset").on('change',':checkbox',function (){$(this).closest("fieldset").find("fieldset :checkbox").not($(this)).prop('checked',false)});
```

[http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/35/edit](http://jsbin.com/acOXisI/36/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck check box by

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", false);
```